# Proper Way To Convert An Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> To Another Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, expression, linq-expressions

I have two expressions.

I have a predicate input of type `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>`

I would like to convert the source expression into type `Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>`

What would be the logic to go about doing this?
I have been trying to use `Expression.Convert()` but I believe I am doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Does `Bar` inherit `Foo`?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Bar` and `Foo`?

Comment: No, `Bar` and `Far` are closely related though.  In my particular case, one is a L2S generated class and the other is my own Data class.  So many properties are similar or the same.  So  they need to be mapped in the conversion somehow.  That is the piece I seem to be missing/need help on.  I have a generic repo method `Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)` where T is my data type. But I need to convert T to the L2S type so I can use it in a Where expression on the L2S context.

Comment: @haim770, see above comment.

Comment: @RufusL, see above comment.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to convert an `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>` into an `Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>` you're going to need an `Expression<Func<Bar, Foo>>` as well, to handle the conversion.

What you're doing then is simply composing expressions.  Composing expressions is slightly more involved than composing functions, where one can simply call the other passing its result as the parameter.  Here we need to replace all instances of the parameter of the second function with the body of the first:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This relies on the following method to replace all instances of one expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

Now we can do the following:

```
Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate = GetPrediate();
Expression<Func<Bar, Foo>> selector = GetSelector();
Expression<Func<Bar, bool>> newPredicate = selector.Compose(predicate);
```

Comment: Where is `GetSelector()` defined?  My assumption is that `GetPredicate()` would be my original expression that I pass in.  I am just confused by your example.

Comment: @IssaFram As I said right from the start, "In order to convert an `Expression<Func<Foo, bool>>` into an `Expression<Func<Bar, bool>>` you're going to need an `Expression<Func<Bar, Foo>>` as well, to handle the conversion."  You need to have it from somewhere, or else create it.  Without knowing anything about these types, I cannot possibly tell you how you should go about creating an expression to convert one to the other.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was just confused at first.  I can make that expression with no issue.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm trying this with a concrete example, and am getting stuck on defining my selector.  Support the Foo type is State and the Bar type is StateBL (from my biz logic layer), and that I have a function, ConvertState, that converts a State to a StateBL.  How  do I turn my ConvertState function into Expression<Func<StateBL, State>>?

Comment: @KC-NH You can't have a method that does the conversion; the query provider will only see that method, not its implementation, and will not be able to translate that into SQL.  You need to create an `Expression` that maps the objects, not a compiled method.